# How can you make mouse events register the TR element as the target

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with tables. What I want is to attach a click event handler to a table and then have the target of that event be the corresponding `tr` element. I used `pointer-events: none` for the `td` elements, but the target of the click events was the table itself (plus my `tr:hover` style was no longer working). If I change the `tr` elements to `display: block` mouse events work like I desire, but now the `td` elements aren't expanded to fill the entire row...

Is there some way around this?

**EDIT:** I should mention that I am hoping for a CSS solution, not JavaSctipt.

**EDIT:** I used a fixed width in my examples, but in actual use the table is automatically sized with a minimum width.

[Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/usd8xmL7/1/)
[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/usd8xmL7/2/)

Comment: Make a function that receives the `event.target` and a selector, and traverses up the `.parentNode`s from the `event.target`, calling the selector on each until the element you want is found, if at all. `while (t && !t.matches(sel)) { t = t.parentNode }`

Comment: @squint Yes, anything is possible with JavaScript... I was hoping there was a simple CSS solution that "just worked."

Comment: Not sure if i understand what exactly is the problem here, but isn't this what you are looking for [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usd8xmL7/3/)

Comment: @DavidDomain I want the table structure in Example 1 with the functionality of Example 2.

Comment: click event handlers are not something that is handled by CSS though....  it is considered good practice to separate the layer of design (CSS) and behaviour (JS) so I really do not see how it is possible to create a proper CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a fixed width table you can just display the tr elements as block and add a `width` rule to your td elements.

**--update--**

OK, since you are not using a fixed width table here the updated snipped, displaying the td elements as floated list items.
Here is an example.

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table');
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 alert(e.target.tagName)
});
```

```css
table {
  min-width: 600px;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

tr:hover {
  background: red;
}

td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: list-item;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Test</strong></td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My bad. I used a fixed width in my examples, but in actual use the table is automatically sized with a minimum width.

Comment: Any reason why you do not want to use a js solution ? Just remove the `pointer-events: none` rule on the `td` elements and the `display: block` rule on the `tr` elements, then in your js do `alert(e.target.parentElement.tagName)`.

Comment: I'll use the JS solution that squint mentioned if I need to, but I was hoping that there was a simple CSS solution that I am not aware of.

Comment: Made an update to my post. Without using fixed width on the td elements.